# Extracting the actual POST parameters from a Rails request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to parse the POST params out of an AJAX form submission in Rails, but for some reason it keeps on including a nested, duplicate version of the parameters, and I'm not sure why.

**AJAX:**

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({foo:'bar',timestamp:Date.now()}),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  });
```

**RAILS:**

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def post_test
    puts "RAW POST: #{request.raw_post}"
    puts "POST PARAMS: #{request.request_parameters().to_json}"
  end

end
```

**RESULT:**

> RAW POST: {"foo":"bar","timestamp":1690813226909}
> POST PARAMS: {"foo":"bar","timestamp":1690813226909,"test":{"foo":"bar","timestamp":1690813226909}}

Why is the `request_parameters()` method including the redundant nested set of parameters?

Comment: it's just packaging the post request to fit the rails convention, placing them in a hash named for the controller, in this case `test`.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly because you have [wrap_parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) configured.

#### Update

Hmm, [looks like that's done automatically now in Rails 7](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-controller-wrap-parameters-by-default), even without `wrap_parameters` configured.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-controller-wrap-parameters-by-default

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading de docs of Ajax on Jquery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you can pass objects, strings, or arrays to the data argument

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: { foo:'bar', timestamp:Date.now() },
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

In this way you can send a complete object without parsing to string and receive it on rails in the following way:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def post_test
    puts "All data: #{params}"
  end

end
```

PD: Sorry for my poor English